# binascii fails on a2b_hqx( b2a_hqx( data ) ) with incomplete number of bytes

Tags: python

Using the Python binascii module, this fails:

```
import binascii
b = binascii.b2a_hqx( 'data' )
a = binascii.a2b_hqx( b )
```

with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
binascii.Incomplete: String has incomplete number of bytes
```

This happens with both Python 2 and 3 (with 3, use b'data' instead).  While it works fine with b2a_base64 and a2b_base64.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yeah, I saw that but if characters are added to make it divisible by 3, then how do you translate the data back?  That is, how would the code that "de-encodes" it know whether characters were added or not?  This issue makes the hqx algorithm completely useless.  And in this sense, people should try thinking a little beyond the superficial before down voting.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
b = binascii.b2a_hqx( 'dataa' )
a = binascii.a2b_hqx( b )
```

> Program exited with error
>   Incomplete(String has incomplete number of bytes)
>   b = binascii.b2a_hqx( 'dataaa' )
>   a = binascii.a2b_hqx( b )

https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html?highlight=b2a_hqx#binascii.b2a_hqx

```
binascii.b2a_hqx(data)
```

Perform hexbin4 binary-to-ASCII translation and return the resulting string. The argument should already be RLE-coded, and have a length divisible by 3 (except possibly the last fragment).